# mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated

Tags: node.js, mongoose

(node:2820) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated,
plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

I am having this issue 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; is not working for me

Comment: Not working how exactly? You need to show the code that is actually causing the problem.

Comment: var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blog_demo", {
    useMongoClient: true,
});

// USERS SCHEMA name,email
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

 var newUser = new User({
     email: "charlie@brown.edu",
     name: "Charlie Brown"
 });
 newUser.save(function(err, user){
    if(err){
         console.log(err);
   } else{
        console.log(user);
    }
});

Comment: That was actually a prompt for you to edit the code in your question instead of trying to post it in a comment, as well as actually explaining what the problem is. So is the problem just the deprecation warning? Or is is actually that your code is doing nothing and hanging there? Because the latter is actually a different problem than what you think it is.